# Plotting best line of fit over a scatterplot of 2 columns of a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, linear-regression, seaborn

I have a scatterplot of two pandas columns: percent price vs percent units sold. 
The scatterplot is generated by plotting multiple products in a for loop. 
How can I plot a regression line over this scatterplot, and how can I fit that data?

I tried using seaborn's sns.regplot() however that was plotting one line for every product in the for loop.

I want one line of fit for ALL the products. 
Any ideas?

My DataFrame looks something like this (randomly generated)

```
        Price % Diff   Sales % Diff
           -23                20
           15                 01
            2                  5 
           -25                50
```

And I have a scatterplot that looks something like this (sample version):

[image]

I want to plot a line of fit over that scatterplot. (Note: Sample DataFrame DOES NOT correspond to picture).

Comment: Please provide a more detailed explanation. Why do you create .a scatter plot with a for loop if you have an existing dataframe?
`sns.regplot('Price % Diff','Sales % Diff',data=df)` should work.

Comment: So I am reading in data from text files/json files, then creating a dataframe with that, then plotting it, for each product in a for loop. I basically just want to know how I can graph a regression line over a scatter plot created from a DataFrame

Comment: `sns.regplot()` works directly on the dataframe. It plots both the scatter and the regression line.
No loop is needed at any point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you have a DataFrame for each product.  If so, then simply use your loop to make a list of DataFrames, and afterwards concatenate them into one:

```
pd.concat(df_list)
```

Then regplot() should produce a fit for all points.